# Why does props.element become undefined when I use it in React?

Tags: javascript, html, reactjs, react-props

I have a React element to which I send

```
<Element first={this.props.first} list1={this.state.list1} list2={this.state.list2} />
```

Both `list1` and `list2` are set by methods called in `componentDidMount()` as they are get requests.

And I am defining and using `Element` like this with `list2` and here the logged `list2` is empty.

```
const Element = (props) => (
      <div className='a'>
        {console.log('something' + JSON.stringify(props.list2))}
        <Link className='class' to={props.list2.find(o => o.name === props.first.name).dead === true
          ? ('/abc/' + (props.first.a ? props.first.a : '')) : ''}>
          {props.first.a ? <i>{props.first.b}</i> : 'Do'}
        </Link>

      </div>
    )
```

Output here is:

> something []

and then

> Uncaught TypeError: Cannot read property 'dead' of undefined

But if I don't use the value of `list2` then it prints the correct list on logging. I mean, for code like this the logged data is correct and non-empty:

```
const Element = (props) => (
          <div className='a'>
            {console.log('something' + JSON.stringify(props.list2))}
            <Link className='class' to={true ? ('/abc/' + (props.first.a ? props.first.a : '')) : ''}>
              {props.first.a ? <i>{props.first.b}</i> : 'Do'}
            </Link>

          </div>
        )
```

Output here is:

> something [{"name":"a", "dead":true}, {"name":"b", "dead":false}]

And output for props.first.name is:

> "a"

I am not able to understand why is this happening. I would appreciate any help.

Comment: Please update your question with a [mcve] demonstrating the problem, ideally a **runnable** one using Stack Snippets (the `[<>]` toolbar button). Stack Snippets support React, including JSX; [here's how to do one](http://meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/338537/). (Please don't use Stack Snippets just for code blocks that aren't runnable. Use code blocks for that.)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Most likely, the first time `Element` is rendered, `props.list2` is empty (or at least doesn't contain a match for `props.exam.id`), but then it's rerendered by the parent component with a non-emtpty list / list with a matching entry. Your code doesn't check that `props.list2.find` found something before trying to use its `dead` property, which will blow up if `find` didn't find anything (for instance, because the list was empty). There should be an error in the web console about trying to use the property `dead` of `undefined`. `find` returns `undefined` if it doesn't find anything.

You'll need to either:

1. Update the logic in `Element` to allow for the possibility `props.list2.find` won't find anything; or
2. Update the parent element so it doesn't render `Element` with a list where `props.list2.find` won't find anything (but that argues for refactoring so the parent passes what you're looking for into `Element`, rather than having `Element` try to find it).

Comment: I have checked with mock data which have the data that I am looking for. The `find` should work. And the issue is that when I print the data without using `find` it does not work and shows empty list but when I don't use `find`, then it shows correct, non-empty list. I have added the console log data for help

Comment: @Panda - The error is **exactly** what you get when `find` doesn't find anything, though. So clearly, again, the component is getting called at least once with a list that doesn't have what you're looking for (then very likely being called again *with* that thing).